# Problemas con Webpack: consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed

Tags: webpack

He estado trabajando sobre un template que fue hecho con nextjs. He hecho varias modificaciones adaptando a requerimientos de quien lo adquirió, funcionaba bien hasta que empezó a dar este problema:

> <w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (545kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)

He buscado en diferentes sitios y no encuentro cómo cambiar o ampliar el buffer, o alguna solución a esto.

Answer (score 0):

Es un error de caché. `PackFileCacheStrategy`. Borra la carpeta `.next` y `node_modules` y vuelve a instalar dependencias y corre el servidor de desarrollo de nuevo.